# How do you perform the deep copy of s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

How do I deep copy artifacts from one s3 bucket to another and preserving the versions that exists for same keys(I know bad design, but that's what I have to work with).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

The version-id of versioned objects is an opaque identifier that is assigned by the system, and is read-only.

For new deployments, there's one exception (sort of): cross-region replication [creates *identical* objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) in the destination bucket, including the same version-id as in the source bucket, but...

> Amazon S3 does not retroactively replicate objects that existed before you added replication configuration.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-what-is-isnot-replicated.html

You'd have to iterate the keys (using List Object Versions) individually, considering the versions and delete markers for each object key in chronological order, copying and/or deleting (oldest to newest, overwriting each older version with the next newest version until you get to the current version), and cross-correlate new bucket's version-id to the old bucket version-id wherever you have the version-ids stored, accessible to the application.